# GCP add timestamp to files in the destination bucket

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform

I have the below cloud function which copies files from one bucket to another in the same project and is working fine. I need to ***add a **timestamp** to the files in the destination bucket*** so that they are not overwritten next time.

```
from google.cloud import storage, bigquery

def archive(event, context):
   
        source_bucket_name = event['bucket']
        blob_name = event['name']
       
        # Initiate Cloud Storage client
        storage_client = storage.Client()
       
        bucketName = 'test_vs'

        # Define the origin bucket
        origin = storage_client.bucket(bucketName)
        
        # Define the destination bucket
        destination = storage_client.bucket('test_vs_archive')

        # Get the list of the blobs located inside the bucket which files you want to copy
        blobs = storage_client.list_blobs(bucketName)

        for blob in blobs:
            
            origin.copy_blob(blob, destination)

        return "Done!"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can read this [document](https://googleapis.dev/python/storage/latest/buckets.html) for API

> copy_blob(blob, destination_bucket, new_name=None,....)
>
> Parameters:
>
> - new_name (str) – (Optional) The new name for the copied file.

So you just need to add Parameters "new_name" to slove:

```
from google.cloud import storage, bigquery
from datetime import datetime

def archive(event, context):
   
        source_bucket_name = event['bucket']
        blob_name = event['name']
       
        # Initiate Cloud Storage client
        storage_client = storage.Client()
       
        bucketName = 'test_vs'

        # Define the origin bucket
        origin = storage_client.bucket(bucketName)
        
        # Define the destination bucket
        destination = storage_client.bucket('test_vs_archive')

        # Get the list of the blobs located inside the bucket which files you want to copy
        blobs = storage_client.list_blobs(bucketName)
        
        # Get datetime
        dt = datetime.today().strftime("%Y-%m-%d")
        
        for blob in blobs:
            n_name = f'{blob.name}_{dt}' # use fstring
            origin.copy_blob(blob, destination, new_name=n_name)

        return "Done!"
```